Lightsail deployment logging; Invalid HTTP_HOST header:You may need to add '****' to ALLOWED_HOSTS
I am deploying a containerised application on Lightsail and whilst the deployment itself is successful, logging shows hundreds of these messages from the same ip address, my assumption is this is some sort of automated process that's failing. I have set the allowed_hosts to just the Lightsail generated url (w/o https//.com etc.) and so I have no idea where this extra ip is coming from. I can't find anything which says I need to have an extra ip on allowed_hosts.
Tried to deploy containerised application to Lightsail

Show us the value of ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
ALLOWED_HOSTS.extend(
filter(None, os.environ.get('ALLOWED_HOSTS', '').split(','))
) And should clarify the complete message is eg; happens every 5 seconds - maybe a health check, but not something I’ve explicitly configured.
[26/Jul/2024:21:50:59] django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.26.31.219'. You may need to add '172.26.31.219' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Have you tried adding 172.26.31.219 to ALLOWED_HOSTS to see if it resolves the warning?

fixed with; ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
ALLOWED_HOSTS.extend(
filter(None, os.environ.get('ALLOWED_HOSTS', '').split(','))
)
ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(gethostbyname(gethostname()))

I've managed to fix it by doing:
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [] ALLOWED_HOSTS.extend( filter(None, os.environ.get('ALLOWED_HOSTS', '').split(',')) ) ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(gethostbyname(gethostname()))

